# Automating a PR merge followed by opening a new PR

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a branch called `stage` and currently have a workflow that runs when a PR is labeled (to merge into the stage branch), and I'm currently trying to create a workflow that happens *if* the branch is successfully automerge.

For example -- here's a working example of the workflow to the `stage` branch:

```
name: PR opened to stage
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [labeled]
    branches: [ stage ]
jobs:
  audit-checks:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        if: contains(github.event.pull_request.labels.*.name, 'ready')
      - name: Enable Auto Merge
        uses: peter-evans/enable-pull-request-automerge@v1
        if: contains(github.event.pull_request.labels.*.name, 'ready')
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          pull-request-number: ${{ github.event.pull_request.number }}
          merge-method: merge
```

And here's *another* workflow that, when a PR to stage is closed, is supposed to run. I have a step as well that checks to see if the label includes `ready` and is supposed to create another PR to another branch:

```
name: ready for prod test
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [closed]
    branches: [ stage ]
jobs:
  audit-checks:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: automate PR creation for prod
        if: |
          ${{ github.event.pull_request.merged }} && contains(github.event.pull_request.labels.*.name, 'ready')
        uses: peter-evans/create-pull-request@v3
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          branch: stage
          base: prod
          labels: ready
          title: Automated PR opened
```

It seems that when the PR is initially opened and labeled `ready`, the first workflow runs just fine. However, once that workflow enables auto merge and it actually auto-merges (upon completion of the workflow), the second workflow doesn't ever get triggered.

Is it possible that the second workflow is somehow running before the first one completes and doesn't actually do anything because of it? I'm not sure it's anything in my 2nd job (at least not yet) since it hasn't even run (or run and fail).

Answer (score 0):

Just found my answer here: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication

> When you use the repository's GITHUB_TOKEN to perform tasks on behalf
> of the GitHub Actions app, events triggered by the GITHUB_TOKEN will
> not create a new workflow run. This prevents you from accidentally
> creating recursive workflow runs. For example, if a workflow run
> pushes code using the repository's GITHUB_TOKEN, a new workflow will
> not run even when the repository contains a workflow configured to run
> when push events occur.